# im receiving error: type Stack does not take parameters and my code is right what will i do

Tags: java

what is wrong with my code? :(
it says error: type Stack does not take parameters i think my codes right idk what will i do?

```java
class Stack  {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 12;
        Stack <Integer> stack = new Stack <Integer>();
        
        while (n>0){
            stack.push (n %2);
            n= n/2;
        }
        String result = "";
        while (!stack.isEmpty());
            result += stack.pop();
            System.out.print(result);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hint: when you write `new Stack <Integer>();` what class *exactly*, including package, are you expecting to use? And what's the name of *your* class?

Comment: Rename your `Stack` class, you run in a naming conflict with `java.util.Stack<E>`.

Comment: Next hint: "my code is right" - no, it's not... but if you start out with the *assumption* that it is, that makes it much harder for you to find the problem. Any time something doesn't work, it's best to *assume* the problem is in your code until you can prove otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use the class name "Stack". It will collide with the `Stack` data structure class you are using (`java.util.Stack`). Rename your class to something like `StackExample`.

Second, remove the semicolon that you have at the end of the `while` loop.

```
import java.util.*;

class StackExample{ //  renaming the class name as StackExample
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 12;
        Stack <Integer> stack = new Stack <Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter elements");
        while (n>0){
            stack.push(n%2);
            n= n/2;
        }
        String result = "";
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) // Removing the semicolon here
            result += stack.pop();
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. However in the future, comments such as "please upvote" or "please click the checkmark" should be omitted.